# How to prevent 2d object from rotating in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making my first ever game (2D) in unity. And i just a flat character move on surface , and put some walls on the edge of screen to stop him from falling over map, but when he hit the wall he rotates. How do i prevent rotating?

Answer (score 5):

If your character has a 2D Rigidbody, you can freeze both position and rotation in any given direction. You can find these options under Constrains in your Rigidbody component.

[image: Ridigbody Component]

Comment: Just a heads up, the rigidbody2d only has one rotaion (z) not 3 (x,y,z)